# Ranking on Google when using "Tools" option for "Past year" or "Past month"

Tags: seo, google

I'm trying to get a website into the search results from "past month" or "past year".

[image]

Normally the website shows up just fine in the general search results when no search date is specified in the search tools, but my client asked to be included in those recent result as well.

Are there any tips or tricks for this? Other then putting  new content on those pages?

Comment: There is nothing for you to do. This is up to the search engine. YOu have no control over this at all. Sorry. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Google mostly uses the date that the page says that it was posted.   WordPress uses text like "Posted on May 3, 2017 by Joe".  Google knows how to parse a line like that out of pages for the purpose of putting them into the correct time order in search by date.

You could also markup the date in the page with datePublished [schema.org markup for a webpage](http://schema.org/WebPage).  That would ensure that the date is machine readable which would presumably make the task easier for Google.

Comment: Google may also use [inception date](https://www.google.com/patents/US8521749) when the date is not present in template, in schema also in sitemap to sort out the search result. In my blog I don't display anywhere but when I do past year search, google return some of my blog post based on inception date.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a WordPress website then you can change the date. Or try to put a recent date and use the data highlighter in search console to highlight it. If you will be lucky, Google might consider it as a new result based on the mentioned date.